# Editorconfig does not work over TRAMP in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, tramp, editorconfig

I have installed editorconfig mode in Ubuntu 14.04, Emacs 24 (manually, as advised on [github](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-emacs)), and it works nicely locally (I also have catch-all .editorconfig in the $HOME dir.)

However, when editing via ssh/tramp on another Ubuntu 14.04 host (tried without and with editorconfig package for EditConfig C Core installed there), .editorconfig-files seem to be totally ignored, not even my home dir one taken into account.

Is it just a sad limitation or am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a [limitation](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/issues/195). One thing you can do is to use `sshfs` to mount a remote file system locally and edit the file via that way.